# Null context with GraphQL DataLoader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql-dotnet

In my project that uses [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet), I unexpectedly started getting errors saying the DataLoader context was null:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
  at GraphQL.DataLoader.DataLoaderContextExtensions.GetOrAddBatchLoader[TKey,T](DataLoaderContext context, String loaderKey, Func`3 fetchFunc, IEqualityComparer`1 keyComparer, T defaultValue)
```

The `context` parameter comes from the `IDataLoaderContextAccessor` that is injected into the constructor of the graph type. Why would it be null?

Comment: The entire graphql-dotnet project is an anti-pattern. I wouldn't expect it to actually work well at the current stage of development for it.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard Well that's weird because I know lots of people using it in production, it works very well indeed.

Comment: That is a scary thought. The whole project is in dire need of refactor.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard Why? It's a reasonably mature product

Comment: The entire project is dripping with code smell and anti-patterns. First thing that comes to mind--  its reliance on the service locator anti-pattern.

Comment: There are definitely parts I would want to refactor, but it works well enough right now.

Answer (score 3):

The `context` parameter will be null if you forget to add the `DataLoaderDocumentListener` before executing the query (like I did):

```
public GraphQLController(
    ISchema schema,
    IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter,
    DataLoaderDocumentListener dataLoaderListener)
{
    _schema = schema;
    _documentExecuter = documentExecuter;
    _dataLoaderListener = dataLoaderListener;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]BaseGraphQuery query)
{
    var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();
    var executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions
    {
        Schema = _schema,
        Query = query.Query,
        Inputs = inputs,
    };

    // Important!
    executionOptions.Listeners.Add(_dataLoaderListener);

    // (Execute the query)
}
```

And `DataLoaderDocumentListener` must be present in the service container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // (other service configuration)

    services.AddSingleton<GraphQL.DataLoader.IDataLoaderContextAccessor, GraphQL.DataLoader.DataLoaderContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<GraphQL.DataLoader.DataLoaderDocumentListener>();
    services.AddSingleton<GraphQL.IDocumentExecuter, GraphQL.DocumentExecuter>();
    services.AddSingleton<GraphQL.Types.ISchema, RootSchema>();
}
```

The accurate but vague error message confused me until I remembered I had "refactored" some code and removed the `Listeners.Add` line by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Also you need to make sure 
`services.AddMvc();`
is before all other stuff in startup.ConfigureServices()

Comment: The order of calls in `ConfigureServices` doesn't matter. It _does_ matter in `Configure`, because that is setting up a response pipeline.

Comment: @NateBarbettini it is what i changed to get my Context filled because it was null before that change.. So not sure about that

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. Are you sure it was `ConfigureServices`? Simply changing the position of `AddMvc` caused a difference? My understanding of it could be wrong.

Comment: Not certain because i changed maybe one other small thing which i think is not related.
I know that the order of things in ConfigureServices can make a difference though